# Preloading audio file with winmm.dll in C#

Tags: c#, audio, preload, winmm, mcisendstring

I am writing a wave audio player using C# and winmm.dll. To reduce the delay while switching from one file to the next, I open the next file with a different alias. While switching to the next file, I stop the first alias, and then play the second one.
Everything works great, until the user waits a while (i.e. 20 minutes) before playing the next (preloaded) file. In this situation the player has a 5 seconds delay before playing the new file, which has been preloaded for a while.

The question is, does winmm.dll put not-used-files in a "standby" mode? Do we need to activate it in certain time periods to reduce the delay? If yes how to do that?

I found a status called "parked" but this is never returned, and I can't find anything on the web describing it.

It would be a great help, if someone could help, cause there is not much documentation out there for this DLL.

[MCI Commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797783(v=vs.85).aspx)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a pretty inevitable consequence of how your operating system works.  If you don't use code or data for a while then it is going to get swapped out of RAM and stored in the paging file.  To make room for whatever other programs you are running.  If you don't have enough RAM or your hard disk is slow or the paging file is badly fragmented then swapping it back in can take a while.  Ask at superuser.com how you can make your machine work better.

Comment: Hmmm... 5 seconds is a long time even if you had not preloaded the file. Is it possible the hard drive is being powered off by your Windows power settings? On my system the default is to turn off the hard disk after 20 minutes. You can check yours in control panel, power options, change plan settings, change advanced power settings, hard disk, turn off hard disk after...

Comment: @HansPassant I check your solution and think that's not true, because  that system has 4GB RAM and use only for this work (use for radio conductor player).

Comment: @jaket This sytem's HDD never powered off and always is on.